# Touch pad only works when mouse is connected Kubuntu

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, touchpad

I am using Kubuntu 16.04.02
When I connect the USB mouse I can use the touch pad but as soon as I unplug it it stops working. When I go into touch pad from settings it says no touch pad is connected?

Isn't that strange?

From touch pad settings this is the pad: HID 04d9:1133

The command that shows hardware shows the touch pad ONLY when the mouse is connected. As soon as it's gone the device ID is gone with it!

Things went worse after updating the kernel, thinking it might bring driver updates. I'm on 4.11 now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: run updates, uplug the mouse, keep it upluged and reboot (ctrl-alt-delete arrow keys enter).  Does it still not detect your trackpad? Open the mouse&touchpad settings screencap it (Alt-Print Screen) and add it to your post. thanks

Comment: OK I'll do that and post the screenshot when I do.

Comment: @tatsu here it is.

Comment: untik "Tap-and-Drag gesture" in the first and both "Disable-touhpad when typing" and "Disable taps and scrolling only" in the second and do OK. does this have better results?

Comment: Sadly it stopped working and the message displayed is: "No touchpad found".

Comment: i think your kubuntu is entirely broken. Are you adamant about using KDE?

Comment: When I downloaded this ISO I checked the checksum and it was a match, installing it went smooth and other than the touchpad issue everything is fine so far.

Comment: @tatsu 
 
I did have a hardware issue were the pins on of the touch pads were twisted due to bad installation (took my laptop apart and didn't bring it back right) so maybe the straightened copper connectors have something to do with this?

Comment: ah yeah! that could be it!

Comment: They worked fine for months, we act up now? I don't feel like taking my laptop apart so it stays the way it is for now @tatsu

Comment: @tatsu Do you have a command or something that could clear the doubts for sure? I'd like to grant your answer as the answer that fixed my issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58732/discussion-between-muaad-elsharif-and-tatsu).

Comment: sorry I'm about to go to bed :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't software related!
Taking apart my laptop I discovered that one of the pins on the touch pad connector was bent. By fixing it and reconnecting the pad works fine - for now-.
Thanks for all the help.